# Evaluating a trace with two factors of $\gamma^5$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, dirac-matrices, trace

In the process of calculating a spin-averaged square amplitude in QFT, I came across the following expression:
$$ \text{Tr}\left[\gamma^\mu\gamma^5\gamma^\alpha\gamma^\nu\gamma^5\gamma^\beta\right] $$
How can I evaluate this? The usual identities [(eg the ones on Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_matrices#Trace_identities) don't seem to be of much use - I can't see any way to do it with those, since there are two factors of $\gamma^5$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just realised that I can use the fact that $\gamma^5$ anticommutes with the others (twice):
$$=\text{Tr}\left[\gamma^\mu\gamma^\alpha\gamma^\nu\gamma^5\gamma^5\gamma^\beta\right]$$
then note that $\gamma^5\gamma^5$ is just the identity, giving:
$$=\text{Tr}\left[\gamma^\mu\gamma^\alpha\gamma^\nu\gamma^\beta\right]$$
which can be expanded by the usual identity, resolving my issue.